# files not copying to a different folder

Tags: php, file

I am trying to move all the .vtk files and .raw files to a different folder. But it is not being copied. How do I fix this?

```
<?php
define ('DOC_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
$src = '/var/www/html/php/';
$dest ='/var/www/html/php/emd/';
$dh = opendir ($src); //Get a directory handle
$validExt = array('vtk','raw'); //Define a list of allowed file types
$filesMoved = 0;

// Loop through all the files in the directory checking them and moving them
while (($file = readdir ($dh)) !== false) {
   // Get the file type and convert to lower case so the array search always matches
   $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo ($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   if(in_array ($fileType, $validExt)) {
      // Move the file - if this is for the web really you should create a web safe file name
      if (!$rename($src.$file, $dest.) {
        echo  "Failed to move {$file} to {$newPath}";
      } else {
        echo "Moved {$file} to {$newPath}";
        $filesMoved++;
      }
   }
}
echo "{$filesMoved} files were moved";
closedir($dh); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the filename for the destination, change this line:

```
if (!$rename($src.$file, $dest.) {
```

into:

```
if (!$rename($src.$file, $dest.$file) {
```

If this is not working make sure that the destination directory really exists and that you have write permission to it. If you had enabled error reporting you would have seen an error message like this:

> Parse error: parse error in
>   /path/to/script/rename.php on
>   line 18